# What is the default GUI backend for Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made the following script, let's call it `test-matplotlib-printbackend.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = range(100)
yy = [i*2+5 for i in xx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xx, yy)

print("Matplotlib plt backend: {}".format(plt.get_backend()))

plt.show()
```

For Python3 under MINGW64 on Windows 10, as well as Python3 under Anaconda on Windows 10, I get the printout:

```
Matplotlib plt backend: Qt5Agg
```

However, for Python3 on Rasbian (Raspberry Pi's Debian OS), I get the printout:

```
Matplotlib plt backend: TkAgg
```

This kind of puzzles me, because I sort of expected TkAgg would be the default GUI backend for matplotlib on *all* platforms !?

So, I just wanted to know - is the default GUI backend for Matplotlib for different platforms documented anywhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The backend selection logic is not very transparent and not well documented.

In modern matplotlib there is no "default backend", i.e. the `rcParams['backend']` is set to a "sentinel".
Upon importing matplotlib the first working backend from [a candidate list](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e23b2aa303763d1c18451f667b44cf0e658d4bf6/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L200) `["macosx", "qt5agg", "qt4agg", "gtk3agg", "tkagg", "wxagg"]` is chosen.

In order to avoid this automatic selection, you can set the backend manually via the `rcParams['backend']` parameter or the `MPLBACKEND` environment variable. That part is [documented](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html?highlight=backend#what-is-a-backend)

Comment: Current [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) says the candidate list is: MacOSX, QtAgg, GTK4Agg, Gtk3Agg, TkAgg, WxAgg, Agg

Answer (score 3):

The default backend is defined in the `mpl.rcParams['backend']`. On Linux_x64 this is set to `'Qt5Agg'`. The `_get_running_interactive_framework` function in the `matplotlib.backends.__init__` checks for available backends. `PyQt5` is highest in the priority list. The `pyplot.switch_backend` function uses `_get_running_interactive_framework` to select the effectively used backend on import. Search for the line `switch_backend(rcParams["backend"])` here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html

You could check whether `PyQt5` is available on Rasbian and what the rcParams entry is.

Comment: Turns out the statement "The default backend is defined in the `mpl.rcParams['backend']`" is inaccurate. Refer to the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58838910/10020283